# PHP copy() - set file size limit?

Tags: php, file, copy

I'm working with a script where I use the PHP function `copy()` in order to save images from URL to my server: `copy('http://si.com/guitar.jpg', 'guitar1213.jpg')`

What I'm wondering is if there's any way I can simply set a max file size limit when calling this function? Or is really `.htaccess` my only option to quickly fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: php.ini is easier to edit for this than .htaccess, but I know this doesn't answer your question as to whether or not it can be done in the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get the file size once the file is on your server, I would recommend downloading the file to a temp folder and then you can easily check the file size and move to the correct location if it meets the requirements.

```
$original_path = 'http://si.com/guitar.jpg';
$temp_location = 'guitar1213.jpg';

$handle = fopen($temp_location, "w+"); 
fwrite($handle, file_get_contents($original_path)); 
fclose($handle); 

if (filesize($temp_location) < 1024000){
  rename($temp_location, 'xxx');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$limit = 1024; //1KB
$fr = fopen($filePath, 'r');
$limitedContent = fread($fr, $limit);
$fw = fopen($filePath, 'w');
fwrite($fw, $limitedContent);
```

[check PHP API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Answer (score 0):

Toyed with the idea of finding the file size first and then perform the copy:

```
<?php

if (false !== ($f = fopen($url, 'rb'))) {
    // read the meta data from the file, which contains the response headers
    $d = stream_get_meta_data($f);
    // find the Content-Length header
    if ($headers = preg_grep('/^Content-Length: /i', $d['wrapper_data'])) {
        $size = substr(end($headers), 16);
        // if the size is okay, open the destination stream
        if ($size <= 10000 && false !== ($o = fopen('destination.jpg', 'wb'))) {
            // and perform the copy
            stream_copy_to_stream($f, $o);
            fclose($o);
        }
    }
    fclose($f);
}
```

**Caveat**

It won't work if the server doesn't return a `Content-Length` header; this is a possibility which might need to be dealt with.